# C unable to read from a file with fgets

Tags: c, file, fgets

I want to read from a file `.txt` into memory in C.

I put `txt` files in same place with source files, so `fileName` is given as `small_addressbook.txt`

When I run code in eclipse (on macbook), it always prints `File not found`, and in Unix, I got `segmentation fault`.

I try running `gdb` in Unix and I got this error report:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strncpy_sse2_unaligned ()
    at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:666
666     mov %rcx, (%rdi)
```

Comment: `char entry[] = EMPTY_STRING;` --> `char entry[100];` or `char entry[100] = EMPTY_STRING;`

Comment: `malloc(sizeof aNode)` --> `malloc(sizeof *aNode)`

Comment: `aNode = (*create)();` :  memory leak

Comment: sorry can you explain more about memory leak in this case?

Comment: Because It was overwritten.

Comment: You can get information about the error if your run the tool Valgrind (http://www.valgrind.org) with your code.

Comment: have you tried to check if your path is correct ? have you tried to check if your var filePath is still valid when used ? maybe you should pass it as const char *

Answer (score -1, accepted):

UNIX `gdb` command is very helpful in detecting any problem with the codes.

For example, if we compile the program with the following command:

`gcc -ansi -Wall -pedantic test1.c test2.c ... -o test`

and got a `segmentation fault`.

Then we use `gdb` command to see problem(s):

`gdb test`
`gdb run`

A report of errors/problems will return. We then can use `bt` command to do back trace in the program.

In this specific post, as we see:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strncpy_sse2_unaligned ()
    at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:666
666     mov %rcx, (%rdi)
```

`SIGSEGV` indicates a signal on segmenting, particularly `Segmentation fault`.

Then `__strncpy__se2__` means the problem is about some value passing to method `strncpy`, and `sse2` means segment 2, like the order of source file `.c` that value is passing to.

Finnally, `unaligned` means this method `strncpy` may be conflicting with some other methods that allocate memory for the value.

Enough information to solve the problem.

Comment: C does not have _methods_

Answer (score 0):

While calling function use absolute file path(Ex: "C:/MyFolder/MyFile.txt")